# Windows 10 says I'm not connected even though I am?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When Cortana makes me log into my MS Account, the window she opens just says 'Something went wrong':

[image: Something went wrong]

Also, when I try and send MS Feedback, I get this:

[image: You'll need the Internet for this]

I find this really strange because I am connected to the internet. I can log into my MS account on the web perfectly so I don't know why this is happening.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Any workarounds?

Comment: is the DNS service running?

Comment: @magicandre1981 If you mean the one called `DNS Client` in `services.msc`, then yes it's running.

Comment: yes, I mean this service.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, the DNS service is running.